Can we use "used to" and "would" with time clauses
Can I use "used to" and  "would" for repeated events in the past in time clauses. I will give some examples

When I would/used to do that, she was happy

I did many different things before I used to/would do that

I remeber when when he used to/would drink a lot


What I know about time clauses is that we don't use future tenses with them. I"m lost when it comes to "used to" and "would", I found no information about them. That's why I'm asking. To be honest 1 sounds good to me. 2 sound wrong and 3 seems correct because I don't think it is really a time clause. Still, I don't really know please give some broad explanation.

Basically used to means was in the habit of. I used to go to the gym each week. I was in the habit of going to the gym each week.

When I used to do that, she was happy. This is not wrong, but it doesn't sound natural to me, I think because when implies a succession of single times. "Each time I did that, she was happy." Possible alternatives: I used to do that, and it made her happy. Or, Whenever I did that, she was happy.

I did many different things before I used to do that. This is unnatural and possibly wrong. You're comparing "many things" with "that one thing." So a more natural expression is "I used to do many different things before I did that."

I remember when when he used to drink a lot. This is fine.


As for would, this has many meanings, so you need to be careful. For example, in I remember when he would (used to) drink a lot, would and used to mean the same thing. But that switch in the second sentence results in this: I did many different things before I would do that. And now would has the sense of was willing to. "I did many things, but that other thing was going too far."

I'd say "when I used to do that, it would make her happy", or "When I used to do that, she would feel happy", unless the intention was to say that one didn't do it at times when she wasn't happy.
